# Where window.screen belongs in this code?

Tags: python, scripting, windows, documentation

```
import bpy
for window in bpy.context.window_manager.windows:
    screen = window.screen

    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
            bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(override)
            break
```

I'm learning blender python with its documentation. The code is one of the example code from the tutorial. What I don't understand is, the variable `screen` doesn't belong to iterable module called `bpy.context.window_manager.windows`. If everything comes together, shouldn't this be `bpy.context.window_manager.windows.window.screen` because variable `window` is a part of the module?

```
>>> bpy.context.window_manager.windows.
                                       as_bytes(
                                       data
                                       find(
                                       foreach_get(
                                       foreach_set(
                                       get(
                                       id_data
                                       items(
                                       keys(
                                       path_from_id(
                                       rna_type(
                                       update(
                                       values(
```

See, there's no module called `window`. All I can see in the console panel is bunch of built-in functions.

```
    for area in screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            override = {'window': window, 'screen': screen, 'area': area}
            bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area(override)
            break
```

This one is same. I can't find `screen.areas` in `area` module. `screen.areas` is iterable and loop is ongoing so it should say `...screen.areas.area.type` yet there's nothing in it. (even `bpy.ops.screen` has no `area.type`.)

What is going on in this code? How can I see visually where the modules are located in my console tab?

Comment: A blender collection is a mapping that behaves like a dictionary and a list. In this case, a particular window is `window = windows[0]` not `windows.window`  This is the case for all collections.  Also a member of a collection is not necessarily a module. _eg_  a list called `ints = [1, 2, 3]`  can be iterated `for i in ints:` there is no expectation that can use `ints.i`.

Comment: @batFINGER Can I understand this is same concept looping nested array in Javascript? o.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing is that bpy.context.window_manager.windows is an iterable:

```
>>> type(bpy.context.window_manager.windows)
<class 'bpy_prop_collection'>
```

In order to see a window, you must choose a member:

```
>>> type(bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0])
<class 'bpy.types.Window'>
```

Or you can chain together something like this since screen.areas is also an iterable:

```
bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0].screen.areas[0].type
```

Comment: Thanks for details. I was literally chocking myself lol